# What is the best way to use Bearer token authentication along with Proxy Digest Authentication? Is it even possible?

Tags: nginx, okhttp, squid, digest-authentication, openresty

We have few Web APIs accessible via **Bearer token** authentication flow. Now, we need to support these APIs with **Proxy** based authentication as well (e.g., Basic, Digest, NTLM). So far, I was able to test **Bearer token** authentication along with **Basic** authentication, now I am exploring **Digest** authentication.

Since Bearer token flow uses **Authorization** header, while Proxy Digest Authentication also has overlapping/conflicting usage of Authorization header in authentication flow between client and proxy server. Can we achieve both authentication schemes (Bearer and Proxy Digest) simultaneously?

- https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7616.html
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617

On the client side, I have used **okhttp-digest** (https://github.com/rburgst/okhttp-digest) library in Java. While for testing the Digest auth scheme on proxy server, I have tried **Squid** server and **Nginx/OpenResty** server with **digest_auth** module (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/auth_digest/), but no luck in any of the proxy servers. In case of Squid server, it replaces the custom **Host** header sent from client side with the current URL's host (not desirable from the Web APIs side). While in case of Nginx/OpenResty, it sends **401** to which okhttp-digest is not compatible in case of proxy authentication.

Is there any way in particular any modules in OpenResty/Nginx which could help me achieve both kind of authentication from client/proxy server side?

Currently, I am looking into how I can send the Bearer token on successful authentication at client side in subsequent request, though I am not sure if it would work or again have conflict at proxy server side.

Client side code using okhttp-digest library.

```
import com.burgstaller.okhttp.AuthenticationCacheInterceptor;
import com.burgstaller.okhttp.CachingAuthenticatorDecorator;
import com.burgstaller.okhttp.DispatchingAuthenticator;
import com.burgstaller.okhttp.basic.BasicAuthenticator;
import com.burgstaller.okhttp.digest.CachingAuthenticator;
import com.burgstaller.okhttp.digest.Credentials;
import com.burgstaller.okhttp.digest.DigestAuthenticator;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Test {

    public static String bearerToken = "Bearer abc";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.3", 80));

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        final Map<String, CachingAuthenticator> authCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        Credentials credentials = new Credentials("username", "password");
        final BasicAuthenticator basicAuthenticator = new BasicAuthenticator(credentials);
        final DigestAuthenticator digestAuthenticator = new DigestAuthenticator(credentials);

        DispatchingAuthenticator authenticator = new DispatchingAuthenticator.Builder()
                .with("digest", digestAuthenticator)
                .build();

        final OkHttpClient client = builder
                .proxy(proxy)
                .proxyAuthenticator(new CachingAuthenticatorDecorator(authenticator, authCache))
                .addInterceptor(new AuthenticationCacheInterceptor(authCache))
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();

        String url = "http://www.example.com";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .method("GET", null)
                .addHeader("Host", "admin.example.com")
                .addHeader("Authorization", bearerToken)
                .get()
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        System.out.println(response.body().string());
    }
}
```

Nginx.conf inside OpenResty (built with auth_digest and other required modules).

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    resolver  114.114.114.114;
#    resolver 8.8.8.8;

log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
'"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
'$request_time req_header:"$req_header" req_body:"$request_body" '
'resp_header:"$resp_header" resp_body:"$resp_body"';

lua_need_request_body on;

body_filter_by_lua '
  local resp_body = string.sub(ngx.arg[1], 1, 1000)
  ngx.ctx.buffered = (ngx.ctx.buffered or "") .. resp_body
  if ngx.arg[2] then
     ngx.var.resp_body = ngx.ctx.buffered
  end
';

header_filter_by_lua ' 
  local h = ngx.req.get_headers()
  for k, v in pairs(h) do
      ngx.var.req_header = ngx.var.req_header .. k.."="..v.." "
  end
  local rh = ngx.resp.get_headers()
  for k, v in pairs(rh) do
      ngx.var.resp_header = ngx.var.resp_header .. k.."="..v.." "
  end
';
    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        set $resp_body "";
        set $req_header "";
        set $resp_header "";

        auth_digest_user_file /etc/proxy/users_digest;
        auth_digest 'realm';
        proxy_connect;
        proxy_connect_allow            443;
        proxy_connect_connect_timeout  10s;
        proxy_connect_read_timeout     10s;
        proxy_connect_send_timeout     10s;
        
        location / {
        add_header X-DEBUG-MSG-1 "$uri";
        add_header X-DEBUG-MSG-2 "$http_authorization";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Host;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;
            proxy_pass $scheme://$host$request_uri;
        }
    
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        set $resp_body "";
        set $req_header "";
        set $resp_header "";

        auth_digest_user_file /etc/proxy/users_digest;
        auth_digest 'realm';
        proxy_connect;
        proxy_connect_allow            443;
        proxy_connect_connect_timeout  10s;
        proxy_connect_read_timeout     10s;
        proxy_connect_send_timeout     10s;

        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            add_header X-DEBUG-MSG-1 "$uri";
            add_header X-DEBUG-MSG-2 "$http_authorization";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
            proxy_pass_header Host;
            proxy_pass_header Authorization;
            proxy_pass $scheme://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.** I think I cannot use **Nginx** with **digest_auth** module as it always returns **401** (with **WWW-Authenticate** response header instead of **Proxy-Authenticate** response header) as it expects digest auth info in **Authorization** request header instead of **Proxy-Authorization** request header. So, for testing the Digest auth scheme, what I need is a **forward proxy server** (something like **Squid** but not **Squid itself** as it messes up with **Host** request header which is not expected in my use-case) which does **Proxy Authentication** rather than **Server Authentication**.